# Paper-scroll-header-panel vs Paper-header-panel

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'll probably get down votes for this, but I have to ask anyways... When would I use `paper-scroll-header-panel` over `paper-header-panel`? The seem to overlap in features- both scroll, both are headers, both share some of the visual effects, etc.

I see they have different attributes and api...but a lack of attributes would not stop me from implementing my own behavior/style. I guess what I would also like is clarification on the intended use between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-scroll-header-panel)

> paper-scroll-header-panel contains a header section and a content section. The header is initially on the top part of the view but it scrolls away with the rest of the scrollable content. Upon scrolling slightly up at any point, the header scrolls back into view.

You can view the [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-scroll-header-panel?view=demo:demo/transform-header-1.html&active=paper-scroll-header-panel) to see this behaviour in action.

`paper-header-panel` just provides a header and scrollable content area, without the "advanced" scrolling behaviour.

Comment: `Upon scrolling slightly up at any point, the header scrolls back into view` is pretty much the only difference I could find. `paper-header-panel` does this also, but only when you go back the very top.

Comment: Yeah that's the main difference. Initially `paper-scroll-header-panel` didn't exist, and a lot of people were using `paper-header-panel`. `paper-scroll-header-panel` was introduced to implement this behaviour which is pretty common on mobile devices. This probably explains why there is two different elements for a seemingly similar behaviour.